# if checkbox is checked a corresponding button should change color

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with a button in each row, as well as a checkbox.
The color of the button should change if the checkbox is checked. This works fine for the first row - When a checkbox is checked, the color of the button changes, and when unchecked it changes back.
But, when the checkbox in the second row is checked, the button in first row changes color

I already managed to get it working for one button, but not with second button

```js
//  If checkbox is checked equipment is NOT in run, then background row equipment change to grey and Color button from red to green-->
function ChangeRowColor(chkrow, row, cel) {
  var varrow = document.getElementById(row);
  var varcel = document.getElementById(cel);
  var varColor = "#E3CEF6";
  var varColor2 = "Yellow";
  if (chkrow.checked == true) {
    varColor = "Grey";
    varColor2 = "Grey";
    document.getElementById("b_echo_01").style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("b_echo_01").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
  varrow.style.backgroundColor = varColor;
  varcel.style.backgroundColor = varColor2;
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: red;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.green,
input.green {
  background: green;
}

.buttonsmall {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: white;
}

.buttonsmall:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <!-- Create extra space -->
  <p><br><br></p>
  <!-- Create extra space -->
  <p><br></p>

  <div id="Echo_O01_button">
    <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;">
      <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
        <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
      </colgroup>
      <tr id="rowA">
        <td width="20%"><input type="button" id="b_echo_01" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px" onclick="showOrHide('Echo_O01')">
        </td>
        <td width="40%"><b>Echo555_O01</></td>
            <td  width="15%"></td> 
         <td  id="celA" width="15%" bgcolor="yellow"><input type="checkbox" name="notinrun6" id="chkrowA" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this,'rowA','celA')"/></td>
            <td  width="10%"></td> 
          </tr> 
          </table>
          </div> <!-- Close Div Echo_O01_button --> 
           <!--  <p><br></p> -->
         <div id="Echo_O02_button">
     <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;" >
     <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
        <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
      </colgroup>
      <tr id="rowB">
        <td  width="20%"><input type="button" id = "b_echo_02" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px" onclick="showOrHide('Echo_O02')">      
        </td>
        <td  width="40%"><b>Echo555_O02</></td>
        <td  width="15%"></td> 
     <td  id="celB" width="15%" bgcolor="yellow"><input type="checkbox" name="notinrun6" id="chkrowB" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this,'rowB','celB')"/></td>
        <td  width="10%"></td> 
      </tr> 
      </table>
      </div> <!-- Close Div Echo_O02_button --> 
  </body>
</html>
```

My desired result is that when an individual checkbox is checked, only the corresponding button changes color.

Comment: So in every row the button has the same ID ? that's a NO NO . You shouldn't have multiple elements with same ID attribute in HTML. After fixing that consider adding a logic that selects the button depending on the relationship with the checkbox. There are multiple ways to do that. If you want more help, post here a working snippet that replicates your problem, because with the code you posted that is not possible.

Comment: If the button would come after the input element inside the HTML, this would be solvable with one line of CSS code: `.checkbox:checked + button { background-color: green; }` I would prefer that if the layout allows it over writing a JS function.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code with the seccond button

Comment: You updated the HTML with a second button with id `b_echo_02` but in javascript you select only the `b_echo_01` . Of course it won't select the second button as well :)

Comment: but how can i also select the second button. This is now example with two buttons but there are about ten buttons with each there own checkbox. And all these buttons should change independiately from the other ones after checking the checkbox

Comment: I have tried adding the second button to the javascript but when i checked one of the checkboxes, both buttons changed color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put a simple demo so you are not confused. basically you can define a css class and toggle this class name for the button whenever the checkbox change event is fired

```js
$(".checkbox").change(function(){
  $("#"+$(this).data("target")).toggleClass("change-to-me");
});
```

```css
#targetButton{
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
}

.change-to-me{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input class="checkbox" data-target="targetButton1" type="checkbox">
<button id="targetButton1">My background</button>

<input class="checkbox" data-target="targetButton2" type="checkbox">
<button id="targetButton2">My background</button>

<input class="checkbox" data-target="targetButton3" type="checkbox">
<button id="targetButton3">My background</button>
```

Updated answer

```js
//  If checkbox is checked equipment is NOT in run, then background row equipment change to grey and Color button from red to green-->
function ChangeRowColor(chkrow, row, cel, btn) {
  var varrow = document.getElementById(row);
  var varcel = document.getElementById(cel);
  var varColor = "#E3CEF6";
  var varColor2 = "Yellow";
  if (chkrow.checked == true) {
    varColor = "Grey";
    varColor2 = "Grey";
    document.getElementById(btn).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(btn).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
  varrow.style.backgroundColor = varColor;
  varcel.style.backgroundColor = varColor2;
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: red;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.green,
input.green {
  background: green;
}

.buttonsmall {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: white;
}

.buttonsmall:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <!-- Create extra space -->
  <p><br><br></p>
  <!-- Create extra space -->
  <p><br></p>

  <div id="Echo_O01_button">
    <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;">
      <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
        <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
      </colgroup>
      <tr id="rowA">
        <td width="20%"><input type="button" id="b_echo_01" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px" onclick="showOrHide('Echo_O01')">
        </td>
        <td width="40%"><b>Echo555_O01</></td>
            <td  width="15%"></td> 
         <td  id="celA" width="15%" bgcolor="yellow"><input type="checkbox" name="notinrun6" id="chkrowA" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this,'rowA','celA', 'b_echo_01')"/></td>
            <td  width="10%"></td> 
          </tr> 
          </table>
          </div> <!-- Close Div Echo_O01_button --> 
           <!--  <p><br></p> -->
         <div id="Echo_O02_button">
     <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;" >
     <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
        <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
      </colgroup>
      <tr id="rowB">
        <td  width="20%"><input type="button" id = "b_echo_02" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px" onclick="showOrHide('Echo_O02')">      
        </td>
        <td  width="40%"><b>Echo555_O02</></td>
        <td  width="15%"></td> 
     <td  id="celB" width="15%" bgcolor="yellow"><input type="checkbox" name="notinrun6" id="chkrowB" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this,'rowB','celB', 'b_echo_02')"/></td>
        <td  width="10%"></td> 
      </tr> 
      </table>
      </div> <!-- Close Div Echo_O02_button --> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works fine for one checkbox with one button. But does it also works for multiple rows with a checkbox and a button on each row. when checkbox is checked only button on same row should change color

Comment: I copied your code and run it, but the buttons did not change from color. Should i add something to the code?

Comment: Hi Andam, I tried the code, but does not run. If i look at the text in code  "data-target" is colored red above but in my case this is black the other parts like class and type and id are colored red

Comment: @Orca hi ok let me edit you code real quick and posted in the answers

Comment: @Orca I think "Mamun" code is what you want. If its not let me know.

Comment: no the code of Manum is based on the wrong html code. I had updated the code and Manun used the old code. There are two buttons with each an other id and also in another rowid in the table

Comment: @Orca look at the answer I have added new one

Comment: Andam thanks for the update. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute [*`id`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document, use [*`class`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead.

On clicking the check box, you can `toggle()` classes based on the checked status like the following way:

```js
function ChangeRowColor(chkrow) {
  var btn = chkrow.closest('.rowA').querySelector(' .b_echo_01');
  chkrow.parentNode.classList.toggle('cell');
  btn.classList.toggle('green');
  btn.classList.toggle('red');
  chkrow.closest('tr').classList.toggle('gray');
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.gray{
  background-color: gray;
}
.cell{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="Echo_O01_button">
  <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;" >
    <colgroup>
      <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
      <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
    </colgroup>
    <tr class="rowA">
      <td  width="20%"><input type="button" class = "red b_echo_01" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px" onclick="showOrHide('Echo_O01')">      
      </td>
      <td  width="40%"><b>Echo555_O01</></td>
      <td  width="15%"></td> 
      <td  class="cell" width="15%"><input type="checkbox" name="notinrun6" id="chkrowA" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this,'rowA','celA')"/></td>
      <td  width="10%"></td>  
    </tr> 
    <tr class="rowA">
      <td  width="20%"><input type="button" class = "red b_echo_01" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px" onclick="showOrHide('Echo_O01')">      
      </td>
      <td  width="40%"><b>Echo555_O01</></td>
      <td  width="15%"></td> 
      <td  class="cell" width="15%"><input type="checkbox" name="notinrun6" id="chkrowA" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this)"/></td>
      <td  width="10%"></td>  
    </tr> 
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mamun, thanks for your solution, but this is based on the wrong code. I placed the wrong code and updated my original code. There are two buttons with different id's and also different row names . So your solution does not do the job with this code. Can you please have another look at it.

Comment: @Orca, what do you mean by wrong code? This solution is based on the code you have provided in your question......

Comment: Hi Manum, what I mean is that in my code the buttons and checkboxes are in separate divs and also are there a number of table rows below each button. Also I use the id's in the rest of the code. Therefor this solution don't solve my problem. Can I send or email you my total code somewhere, then it will be better to understand for you how it looks like and what my problem is.

Comment: @Orca, nobody can help you when your actual code is something different than the code you are showing here!!!

Answer (score -1):

You are always using the same ID button in your function. To make it work with multiple buttons, you must pass the ID button to function too. (and adapt the function). Something like this:

```
function ChangeRowColor(chkrow,id, row, cel) {
  var varrow = document.getElementById(row);
  var varcel = document.getElementById(cel);
  var varColor = "#E3CEF6";
  var varColor2 = "Yellow";
  if (chkrow.checked == true) {
    varColor = "Grey";
    varColor2 = "Grey";
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
  varrow.style.backgroundColor = varColor;
  varcel.style.backgroundColor = varColor2;
}
```

Then, in html pass that id, something like:

```
<td  id="celA" width="15%" bgcolor="yellow"><input type="checkbox" name="notinrun6" id="chkrowA" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this,'b_echo_01','rowA','celA')"/></td>
```

Comment: I have changed the code . So also the seccond button is visible

Comment: The problem is in your javascript function. I edited the answer so you maybe understand it better.

Comment: Hi LuSchink, the result is now that the background of the row in the table changes from color, but not the color of the  button